# on-change doesn't work on v-select

Tags: vue.js

I tried to use a v-select who display all countries. so i did :

```
<v-select on-change="updateCountryId" label="country_name" :options="countries" ></v-select>
```

it works great and display my countries but the function updateCountryId doesn't seems to work

```
methods: {
    updateCountryId: function() {
        alert('ok');
    }
}
```

but i never see the ok

to import vue-select I did :

```
<script src="/js/vue-select/vue-select.js"> </script>
```

i use it in a twig file so in my vue-select.js i rewrite what i found on https://unpkg.com/vue-select@1.3.3 but replace the {{ }} by <% %>

ps : i already tried v-on:change, @change and onChange

and my code looks like that (i skip thing i judge useless)

```
<div id="General">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Pays :</label>
    <v-select  onChange="updateCountryId" label="country_name" :options="countries" ></v-select>
</div>
.
.
.
<script src="/js/vue-select/vue-select.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.config.delimiters = ['<%', '%>'];
  Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#General",
    data: {
        countries: [],
    }, 
    filters: {
    },
    methods: {
        updateCountryId: function () {
            console.log('ok');
            alert('ok');
         },`
```

Comment: Are you using Vue 1x? For Vue 2x you should use 2x version of vue-select

Comment: @wostex i trie to replace what i have in vue-select.js with what i found on  https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.2.0 But i couldn't even find the {{ }} so i let it like that but my select doesn't work at all with it

Comment: [vue-select](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/) accepts a callback as an `onChange` prop

Comment: @RoyJ tried too...

Comment: use @input instead of change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are missing the colon :

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
  options: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  selected: ''
},

methods: {
    updateCountryId: function() {
        alert('ok');
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
<!-- use the latest release -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>

<div id="app"> 
<v-select :on-change="updateCountryId" label="country_name" :options="options" :searchable="false" ></v-select>
</div>
```

## Update

you need to use [unpkg.com/vue-select@2.0.0](http://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.0.0) because version 1 is not **compatible** with the current version of `Vuejs`

Comment: i have all of that. Except for the
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>
because, as i said, i'm in a .twig file and not a .vue so i wrote what i found on https://unpkg.com/vue-select@1.3.3 on a file named vue-select.js and add 
<script src="/js/vue-select/vue-select.js"> </script>
if i write what's one @latest my v-select doesn't work at all

Comment: so when you change your select what error do you get in the console?

Comment: with the @latest ?

Comment: You need to instsll version 2 because v 1 is no compatible with the current version of vuejs

Comment: No error in the console. The select just doesn't show

Comment: so i tried to replace <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.13/vue.min.js"></script> with <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>

but my page doesn't charge at all. What it did before

Comment: I am talking about vue-select not vuejs

Comment: I tried both. When i use 2 for v-select my select doesn't show at all and no error in the console. For the 1 i had to replace the {{ }} by <% %> bc i'm on twig but for the 2, no occurence of {{ was on the file

Comment: would you please add your twig template to your question

Comment: You have not applied what i suggested at all why you are using onChnage please try to use `:on-change` and i need to know what version do you use for both vue and vue-select

Comment: ok i already tried the on-change, onChange, :onChange and v-on:change. But you were right, i missread what you wrote and thought you wrote `on-change` i tried with the `:on-change` and it looks like it works. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: yeah i read again what u wrote and it was clearly my fault. Sorry for not paying more attention.

Comment: Do not be sorry you are doing great.

Answer (score 5):

you can do this

```
  <v-select :options="etat_nip" v-model="etat_nip_selected"></v-select>
```

and add the v-model "etat_nip_selected " in watch like this

```
watch:{
      'etat_nip_selected'  : function (val, oldval) {
          console.log(val);
      }
    },
```

for more informations https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. Change and inout didn't work at all

Answer (score 4):

Ok, this was really causing me some headache, it seems it has changed again on version 3. Per the documentation (https://vue-select.org/guide/upgrading.html#index-prop-replaced-with-reduce), they removed these 3 functions: onChange, onInput, onSearch in favor of using an event: @input

```js
export default {
    name: 'app',
    methods: {
        changedValue: function() {
            alert("A new value was selected");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<v-select 
    options: ['one', 'two', 'three']
    selected: ''
    @input="changedValue" >
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

For `vuetify 3` I found out I have to add `return-object`, to be able to use array of objects:

```
<v-select v-model="selectedValue"
          :items="itemOptions"
          item-title="title"
          item-value="value"
          @update:modelValue="triggerFoo"
          return-object
/>
```

For options is:

```
const options = [{
  title: 'option 1',
  value: 'value 1,
}, {
  title: 'option 2',
  value: 'value 2'
}]
```

Comment: this is solve my problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I use `@input` not `@change`

Comment: This is more of a comment. The answer should be detailed and complete.

Comment: Thank you Yaman Ashraf. This was the only thing working for me.

Answer (score -1):

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);
new Vue({
el: '#app',

data: {
  options: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  selected: ''
},

methods: {
    updateCountryId: function() {
        alert('ok');
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
<!-- use the latest release -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@latest"></script>

<div id="app"> 
<v-select :on-change="updateCountryId" label="country_name" :options="options" :searchable="false" ></v-select>
</div>
```

Comment: some explanation wouldn't hurt.